# How to add padding-left in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I change the  `padding-left` for an element in JavaScript? I have used this code and it works:

```
$(".number_1").stop().animate({height: '295px', width: '210px', opacity: 1}, 100);
```

However, when I add `padding-left` to the code, it doesn't work:

```
$(".number_1").stop().animate({padding-left: '10px', height: '295px', width: '210px', opacity: 1}, 100);
```

How do I add `padding-left` in code for it to work?

Comment: when using css attributes in javascript, is paddingLeft or backgroundColor, instead of padding-left or background-color.

Comment: use paddingLeft variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String in key for objects without quotes only work when they can be parsed successfully.
Add quotes around padding left and that should work.

```
$(".number_1").stop().animate({"padding-left": '10px' ,height: '295px' ,width: '210px' ,opacity: 1}, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

add quote`(")` if using `padding-left` or change first latter into upper case if properly have `-` then use `paddingLeft`

```
$(".number_1").stop().animate({paddingLeft: '10px' ,height: '295px' ,width: '210px' ,opacity: 1}, 100);
```

OR

```
$(".number_1").stop().animate({"padding-left": '10px' ,height: '295px' ,width: '210px' ,opacity: 1}, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap the style rule in quotes:

```
.animate({'padding-left' : '20px' });
```

Or you can use this:

```
 $("#p1").animate({paddingLeft:"+=100px"});
```

Here is a [W3Schools Tryit Editor](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_ani_paddingleft) demonstrating how to use 'padding-left' or 'paddingLeft' in JQuery animations.

Answer (score 0):

Try  'paddingLeft' instead of 'padding-left'.

Comment: In my eyes this is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: I can't comment because I'm 41 but still want to help people. BTW, paddingLeft may be a solution particularly for this question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can see and click on the link "add a comment" on above question.

Comment: @Litestone I have to say sorry. I checked the previlegs page and yes you are right. You cannot add some comments because 9 reputations points are still missing. I visited the page for previlegs for ages. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

Use `paddingLeft` when you're working with javascript, although in this specific case `'padding-left'` might also work (not entirely sure on that though, as that would be a jQuery specific implementation thing).

```
$(".number_1").stop().animate({paddingLeft: '10px' ,height: '295px' ,width: '210px' ,opacity: 1}, 100);
```

And just a general tip, you should not put a space before the comma, but after it.